# Best way to cast int(primitive) to Long(wrapper) in Java

Tags: java, casting, integer, long-integer, autoboxing

I have a primitive type int "pubNumber" in Java.

I want to convert it to **"[Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Long.html)"(not primitive)**, As per my understanding, there are below ways to do the same.

```
1. Long.valueOf(pubNumber)
2. (long) pubNumber
3. new Long(pubNumber)
```

Can anyone please help me on which one is the best way to do the same and why?

Comment: OP - define best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Long.valueOf(pubNumber)` is the best way to do so because it uses values from cache if it is present.

Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html)

> `public static Long valueOf(long l)`
>   Returns a Long instance
>   representing the specified long value. If a new Long instance is not
>   required, this method should generally be used in preference to the
>   constructor Long(long), as this method is likely to yield
>   significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently
>   requested values. Note that unlike the corresponding method in the
>   Integer class, this method is not required to cache values within a
>   particular range.
>
> **Parameters:** l - a long value.
>   **Returns:** a Long instance representing l.
>   **Since:** 1.5

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid `new Long(pubNumber)`, since that one will always create a new `Long` instance.

On the other hand, `Long.valueOf(pubNumber)` will return a cached `Long` instance if the value to be converted to `Long` is between -128 and 127.

`(long) pubNumber` should behave the same as `Long.valueOf(pubNumber)`, since after the casting to `long`, it will be auto-boxed to `Long`, and I believe the auto-boxing of the `long` to `Long` uses `Long.valueOf()`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between Long.valueOf(pubNumber) and new Long is that using new Long() you will always create a new object, while using Long.valueOf(), may return you the cached value of long if the value is between [-128 to 127].

So, you should prefer Long.valueOf method, because it may save you some memory.